# I need to get cookies from GET call API inside route.js

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, next.js13

I have created a website in Next.js 13 and have a route named `/api/users/me`. Inside that route, I have to get the cookies to extract the token.
when i call the route api frome the browser i get the result that i want, but while i try to call it from the frontend page it gett null in the cookies

in src/api/users/me/route.js

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { connectDB } from "@/dbConfig/dbConfig";

connectDB();

export async function GET(request) {

  try {

    console.log("Token is: ", request.cookies); // expect to get cookies, but null
    return NextResponse.json({ msg: "success" }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { msg: "can't get data", err: error.message },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

in src/app/profile/page.jsx

```
import UserDetails from "@/components/UserDetails";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

async function getData() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const token = cookieStore.get("token"); // here i get the cookies
  try {
    console.log(token.value);
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/users/me`, {
      headers: {
        userToken: String(token.value), // try to pass it in the headers
      },
    });
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch data, please try another time");
    }

    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error loading topic", error);
      }
}

async function ProfilePage() {
  const data = await getData();

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center min-h-screen">
      <h1 className="font-bold text-3xl">Profile page</h1>
      <p className="text-gray-600">This is the profile page</p>
      <UserDetails />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProfilePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a valid api route. Api routes should be defined in `route.js` file.

Move your `src/api/users/me.js` to `src/app/api/users/me/route.js`

For cookies, checkout this documentation - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#dynamic-functions

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
 
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const token = cookieStore.get('token')
 
  return new Response('Hello, Next.js!', {
    status: 200,
    headers: { 'Set-Cookie': `token=${token.value}` },
  })
}
```